# Internet Explorer conditional formatting works when using greater than, but not less than

Tags: internet-explorer, formatting, conditional-statements

Adding this to the head of the page

```
<!--[if gt IE 6]> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie.css">
    <script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

works perfectly, however attempting this

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie.css">
    <script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>

<![endif]-->
```

does nothing. As far as I can tell, if one works so should the other. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Could try using lte instead of lt?

Or, since 10 and 11 don't support conditional comments, what about trying this instead:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie.css">
    <script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx